# My computer crashed after trying to install wine 1.4

Tags: installation, wine

There's more than a week that I tried to install the program `wine 1.4` on my Asus Eee PC and it failed. Since then, all that appears after restarting my mini-laptop is the black screen with a cursor **`_`**, or the message:

```
* Stopping System V runlevel compatibility [ok] 
* Starting
```

What command should I do to return to my computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of how the two are related. This sounds like a graphics driver issue.

Try: Ctrl+Alt+F1 to get to a console. 
Assuming this works try re-installing your graphics driver. For example if it's an Nvidia card (I doubt an Eee PC has Nvidia) try:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-<driver version here>
```

If you need need further help, post the video card installed and Eee PC model. 
You can determine the card by running:

```
lspci -v | grep VGA
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, it didn't work. I suppose that on this Eee PC 4G there's no Nvidia card. Adter trying "sudo apt...." as you said, I restarted the computer and now the new message is:

Comment: *starting NTP server ntpd [ok]

Comment: The Nvidia card was an example. I've no idea what video card in on your system. What's the output of : lspci -v | grep VGA

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your issue using **Recovery Mode**

Follow these steps:

- When your system start chose **Recovery Mode** (*2nd* option from **Grub Menu**). If your system starts automatically without any **Grub Menu** you may have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting to get **Grub Menu**.
- When system starts in **Recovery Mode** go to **grub** option from the list. Select `yes` for the question asked. It will update grub and exit.
- Select **network** from the list to enable Network.
- then finally select **root** in order to login as root.
- Once loged in as root execute following commands to fix your issue..

  ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove wine
   sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
   sudo find / | grep wine | grep -v "/var/cache/apt/archives" | sudo xargs rm -r -f
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo apt-get -f install
   sudo dpkg --configure -a
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure -a
  ```

  Last command would take some time so wait..
- Finally reboot your system.

  ```
   sudo update-grub && sudo update initramfs -u
   sudo reboot
  ```

  **Note:** Since you are loged in by `root`, `sudo` will not be needed..

Reply if something goes wrong.. It should fix your problem..

Comment: unfortunatelly, after the command:sudo find / | grep wine | grep -v "/var/cache/apt/archives" | sudo xargs rm -, it shows me a seria of messages as: rm: cannot remove: is a directory and then "xargs: rm: No such file or directory". And then, all those commands that you suggested to me get as an answer: "No such file or directory" (including the command of reboot)

Comment: Are you sure you executed that command without any error? You might have missed something.. I suggest you to repeat the step once again. Skip `sudo find / | grep wine | grep -v "/var/cache/apt/archives" | sudo xargs rm -r -f` its not that much important. You have to force shutdown your system, and restart it again in `recovery mode`. Execute each commands precisely.. Reply..

Comment: I restarted and then entered again the recovery mode. It started by himself to make commands. In the last lines it's like: [7995588] Kernel Panis - not syncingL Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0%00000100, [799588] Pid: 1, comm: run-init tainted 3.5.0-36-generic #57-Ubuntu. And then some "Call Trace"...

Comment: sorry! I didn't get you!!

Comment: I restarted the computer and chose the Recovery Mode and then the pc started to run some commands by itself; I can reproduce here the last lines that appear on the black screen... if it hels you to get the picture?!

Comment: Actually `Recovery Mode` starts like that only.. It will show a lot of text lines, after sometime it will start and show the menus as shown in [this picture](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=recovery+mode&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=fspRUsS8NcrtrQefsYGgDg&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1365&bih=579&dpr=1#q=ubuntu+recovery+mode&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=3QqNdfsJlcI_tM%3A%3B-Ws-lu1yrS6GoM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fankyo.c.blog.so-net.ne.jp%252F_images%252Fblog%252F_7b2%252Fankyo%252FSS-recovery-mode-002-94692.JPG%253Fc%253Da0%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fankyo.blog.so-net.ne.jp%252F2012-03-23%3B736%3B484)

Comment: after getting the menus, you've to follow the steps as I described in my answer..

Comment: My computer opened directly to th GNU GRUB menu. I had to choose from a list of four: Ubuntu, Advanced options for Ubuntu, Memory test (memtest86+), Memory text (memtest86+, serial console 115200). So I chose "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then "Ubuntu with Linux 3.5.0-36 generic (recovery mode). Then appeared the message "loading Linux" and a long seria of lines, the last ones reffering to something like: "[7.998684] Call Trace:"

Comment: yes yes, you are going right.. then what happened after that?

Comment: Still waiting. As soon as I get something, I update you. Thanks!

Comment: so your system never starts after that last message? Hmm! Something weird is happening with your system!! Does your system starts normally, I mean without `Recovery Mode`??

Comment: I hope so, it starts with loading linux and then a rapidly seria of lines, the last ones reffering to call trace, and the very last one: "[7.999232] [<c14c9ef4>] syscall_call +0x7/0xb". Then it's the blinking cursor (there are almost 10 minutes that it blinks). Without Recovering Mode, my system DOES NOT start

Comment: Larisa, it seems so difficult to fix these issues, although I suggest you [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/ubuntu-10-10-boot-problem-865763/) and [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1662375) If they don't help you then the last option is to re-install Ubuntu. You can use `Live CD/DVD/USB` to prevent your data first then install it. I'm sorry, I couldn't help you.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You said you installed wine but I noticed you later mentioned Nvidia drivers for your notebook. ("I suppose that on this Eee PC 4G there's no Nvidia card.")

By any chance, were you trying to install graphics drivers using Wine?

I found this information about your Asus.
"the Eee PC is a compact and low power sub-notebook. It is based on the Intel 915GM chipset and is powered by a 900MHz Intel Celeron processor."

Your notebook uses Intel Graphics so I suspect you have somehow replaced the correct drivers with a corrupted install of Nvidia drivers.

Since you haven't been able to use your netbook for over a week, I would ask if you have anything on it you want?
I
f you do not I think you would be better off just doing a fresh install of Ubuntu.
Also you need to always find out exactly what hardware you have before trying to install drivers or else you may well be back to the blinking cursor.

Comment: I was trying to install wine in order to use office (microsoft office). On the other hand, I do not have something important on this mini-computer, so if necessary, I'm ready to reinstall Ubuntu or, better, windows xp, which seems more comfortable for me.

Comment: If you need Microsoft Office. Linux isn't going to work well for you.

Comment: How could I install Windows on this Eee PC, using an usb? 4G are enough to support Windows?

Comment: I'd use an external CD-Rom and a Windows CD. You should be able to get XP on and a limited MS Office. The newest MS Office wants 3G itself, so it's going to be tight. Don't install components you don't need. LibreOffice works fine for me. If you don't truly "NEED" MS Office. Consider reinstalling with Lubuntu (It's light) and install LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install Windows XP or even Windows 7 on your Asus you can do that using a 
flash drive.
You need to download a program called Win2Flash.  It is very easy to use and it burns XP 
or windows 7 to your flash drive so you can boot to it and install in to your notebook.

Comment: Why do you need Microsoft Office? Have you tried Libreoffice? And there is a new Office suite that tries to be a clone of MSOffice. It is called Office Suite Free 2013 by Kingsoft.  Here is a link to see it: http://www.kingsoftstore.com/index

Comment: Please, can you explain me exactly how could I install Windows XP on this Asus Eee PC 4G? As I said, my ubuntu on it is crashed, but I have this instruments: a laptop Asus on Windows, a very good conexion at internet and a 4gb usb. (but without damaging my Asus on Windows)

Comment: Hi,  download win2flash. Open it. You have to place a copy of winxp or win7 in your cd or DVD drive and point win2flash to it as the source. Win2flash will automatically install it to your flash drive and it will also make it so it is ready to install from the drive.  You just have to boot to the usb flash drive to start the install.

Comment: If you do not have a CD or DVD copy of winxp or win7 then you can use an ISO copy of them for the install. You will need a program called Daemon Tools Lite. You install Daemon tools and it will allow you to mount the iso file as if it were a virtual CD on your computer. Then run win2flash and point it to the virtual CD drive that you created with windows on it.

Comment: I feel I need to tell you that I have an HP Mini 1110NR and it was not able to run winxp or win7. It is simply too slow. It has an N270 intel processor. I tried quite a few Linux distros including several of the Buntus but none of them recognized the onboard wifi. The netbook hasn't any ethernet on it, only wifi. Finally I downloaded PCLinuxOS Mate edition and tried that. It works perfectly on my netbook. Recognized my wifi, etc and everything. What is really amazing is the speed my netbook runs at. I can play 480p youtube videos on it without any trouble. Everything runs on it flawlessly.